# Is there a way to trap and forward network requests from an iOS app in Java automation code?

Tags: java, automation, functional-testing, mockserver

Is there a way to intercept network requests emanating from an iOS app in Java (Appium) automation code? Basically I want to mock the server calls with a local server but my requests are protobuf requests so I am unable to use a library like www.mock-server.com. There seems to be another project https://github.com/mkopylec/charon-spring-boot-starter but it also seems to reverse proxy URLs of the application it deploys and not an external application. Basically I want to be able to use an API that can reverse proxy calls from another app from my automation Java code but still be able to deal with Protobuf requests.

thanks,
Paddy